# Error 1962: No operating system found!

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 by USB drive. I choose Universal-USB-Installer to make the USB drive just as the official website says. In this process, I chose to erase the whole disk and the default partition scheme. However, after I restarted the computer, the screen prompted:

> Error 1962: No operating system found!

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: did the installation complete?? which drive did you select for the installation?

Answer (score 1):

I asume the OS installed in your internal hard drive is still there and you only formatted the external drive.

Try entering to the BIOS and enabling boot from external drives, or disabling the "safety mode" which cause you can not boot from a USB drive (read the manual provided by the manufacturer for any question).

Comment: Thinks for answering me.I have know the reason.I made a stupid mistake.
My machine is 32 bits,but I choose the 64 bits' ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I made a stupid mistake.

My machine is 32 bits,but I choose the 64 bits' ubuntu system.

I waste a lot of time on this problem because I always thought that there is something wrong with the boot file.

Comment: close the question or remove it